# How to easily get resource location in mac os x, using CoreFoundation?

Tags: macos, core-foundation

I'm passing **const char*** value into the function wich opens the specified audio file with **AudioFileOpenURL** method. So I need an CFURLRef value. But I'm using relative path, like
*sounds/click.wav*
but in this case **AudioFileOpenURL** fails to open file (File not found error). So I need to expand relative path and pass full path into this method. The best solution I found was:
get bundle url, get resource folder url, construct CFURL from CFString, which was constructed from bytes..... very annoying.

```
    CFBundleRef bundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef bundleUrl = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(bundle);
CFURLRef resUrl = CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL(bundle);
CFStringRef cfsName = CFStringCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (UInt8*)inFilePath, strlen(inFilePath), kCFStringEncodingASCII, 1);

CFMutableStringRef fileName =  CFStringCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, CFURLGetString(bundleUrl));
CFStringAppend(fileName, CFURLGetString(resUrl));
CFStringAppend(fileName, cfsName);

CFURLRef theURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, fileName, 0);

CFRelease(fileName);
CFRelease(cfsName);
CFRelease(resUrl);
CFRelease(bundleUrl);
```

Is there a easier way to do so? Because on the iPhone the next code:

```
CFURLRef theURL = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, (UInt8*)inFilePath, strlen(inFilePath), false);
```

working like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of that CF string-creation busy-work is because you're starting from a C string. Start from a [literal CFString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/CFSTR) or NSString instead and you will be much happier.

Once you are passing the subpath into your function as a CF/NSString, use `CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent` to append that subpath to the bundle's resources directory URL. The resulting URL is the URL to the sound file.